# How can I find all folders with a specific name and delete all contents except for two files with a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch, file-management

To clean up a project I need to find all (sub)folders named `palette-library` starting from the current location of a batch script file and then delete all its contents except for a folder called `penstyle-opacity textures` and a file called `penstyle-opacity.plt`. I use Windows 7.

I Googled a lot but so far I only found snippets that can either search, find and delete all the contents of a folder or delete all except the specific file from a pre-defined location. However, I can't manage to put the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but you can first archive files by mask, then erase your file tree, and then unpack archive with paths.

For example:

```
7z a -r my_archive penstyle-opacity.plt
```

or:

```
7z a -r my_archive "palette-library\penstyle-opacity textures\penstyle-opacity.plt"
```

Try and choose what fits you better.

Comment: Thank you! Isolating the two files that I want to keep first is a great idea, but unfortunately that is only part of the solution. I still need the other steps to be automated as well...

Answer (score 0):

First parameter is the folder to delete, the rest is a list of file exceptions, wildcards allowed, will delete all folders and it's subfolders except files matching the list.
Trick is to Hide all exceptions first, and unhide them after delete.

```
@echo off

rem test routine
call :DELDIREXCEPT "c:\testfolder" "pru 2" "must leave.docx" *.jpg *.png *.exe


GOTO :FIN

REM   * * * *  SUBROUTINES FROM HERE  * * * *
REM

:DELDIREXCEPT
  rem deletes folder except a list of files
    rem  ~ removes quotes
  set delDir=%~1
  if not exist "%delDir%" goto :FIN
  pushd %delDir% 2>nul || goto :FIN
    rem get rest of params
  shift
  rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357315/how-to-get-list-of-arguments/34920539#34920539
  rem Delayed expansion disabled in order not to interpret "!" in param values;
  rem however, if a param isn't quoted, chars like "^", "&", "|" get interpreted
  setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
  set param_0=0
  :repeat
    set "lastparam=%~1"
    set /a param_0+=1
    if defined lastparam (
      set "param_%param_0%=%lastparam%"
      echo Hide: "%lastparam%"
      attrib "%lastparam%" +h /s /d 2>nul
      shift
      goto :repeat
    ) else set /a param_0-=1

  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  echo .. deleting %delDir%
  del /s /q /a-h *.* 2> NUL
  echo ...
  :: unhide arguments
  for /l %%Z in (1 1 %param_0%) do (
    echo/ unHide: "!param_%%Z!"
    attrib /s /d "!param_%%Z!" -h 2>nul
  )
  popd
goto :FIN
REM END DELDIREXCEPT


:FIN
```